# Obliviously computing the Least common multiple of two poylnomials

Tags: public-key, protocol-design, homomorphic-encryption

Consider I have two polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$ of the same degree. I want to secure them (using any kind of encryption except FHE) and outsource them to an untrusted server. I want him to compute the least common multiple (LCM) of these two polynomials and return it to me.

- Question: Is there any protocol supporting above scenario ?

Or

Consider a more simpler scenario:

I have $C_1= a\cdot b \bmod p$ and $C_2=a \cdot d \bmod p$, where $p$ is a prime number. I want to outsource $C_1$ and $C_2$ using any form of encryption (other than FHE) and want to delegate GCD computation on these two values to a server without he knows the result (which is $a$).

Comment: What ring are those polynomials over? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer can be a field e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: Why not FHE? You could do a secure 2-party computation.

Comment: @mikeazo Yes, you're absolutely right; but I'd like to avoid using FHE or circuit based operation due to its inefficiency compared to the operation specific one (if I could have one)